# MacOS does not reconnect on 5Ghz when DFS kicks in

Tags: network, wifi, airport

My wireless router (Fritzbox 6591) occasionally has to disable some 5Ghz channels because of DFS (dynamic frequency selection and we're quite close to an airport) priorities. Unfortunately, it seems that my MBP fails to respond correctly and simply drops the connection and does not reconnect: this isn't temporary but will persist until a connection is manually reestablished. Is there anyway around this apart from selecting channels which are not covered by DFS?

We have about 10 devices on the network and it is only the Macs that suffer from the problem.